# What does this java method do with bitwise operations?

Tags: java, image-processing, binary, bitwise-operators

Im not familiar with bitwise operations. This is an image manipulation algorithm. What is happening?

```
void binarize50(int pixels[]) {
        for(int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
            int gray = ((pixels[i] & 0xff) + ((pixels[i] & 0xff00) >> 8) + ((pixels[i] & 0xff0000) >> 16)) / 3;
            pixels[i] = gray < 128 ? 0xff000000 : 0xffffffff;
        }
}
```

I found out that (pixels[i] & 0xff) just "normalizes" somehow and let the pixel/byte become a positive value between 0..255.

What does (pixels[i] & 0xff00 >> 8) do?
What is 0xff00?
And why if grey < 128 the pixel becomes 0xff000000 or else 0xffffffff?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The & operation with the `0xff` and the like applies a bitmask. It's a bitwise and operation. Since an int in Java is 32-bit, you can read `0xff` as `00000000_00000000_00000000_11111111`, `0xff00` as `00000000_00000000_11111111_00000000` and so on. They just omit the leading zeroes.

So if you do `pixels[i] & 0xff`, what's happening is that you get an int of which the last 8 bits are the same as in pixels[i] with the remaining ones set to zero.

The `>>` operator is the right shift. It will shift the bit pattern to the right over the number of bits indicated. If `b` contained `00110011_11001100_00010110_01001100` and you did `b >> 8`, you'd end up with `00000000_00110011_11001100_00010110`. The last 8 bits "dropped off", while to the left zeroes have been shifted in. I don't remember if this operation will shift in 1's to the left if the leading bit was 1, so maybe someone can confirm or deny that.

Knowing this, let's take a look at this line:

```
int gray = ((pixels[i] & 0xff) + ((pixels[i] & 0xff00) >> 8) + ((pixels[i] & 0xff0000) >> 16)) / 3;
```

What happens here is that we make an int as follows (not exact code execution order, just for illustration):

- pixels[i] is masked so only the last 8 bits are retained, the rest become 0.
- pixels[i] is masked so only the bits 8 - 15 (counting right to left, starting from 0) are retained, the rest become 0. That result is then shifted 8 bits to the right. If we started with 00001111_00001111_10101010_00110011, this would result in 00000000_00000000_00000000_10101010.
- pixels[i]  is masked so only the bits 16 - 23 are retained, then shifted 16 bits to the right.
- the results of the above three operations are added and...
- that result is divided by 3.

So what does this achieve? Well, what it basically comes down to is that the first 8 bits of pixels[i] are ignored, and the following 3 sections of 8 bits are each interpreted as a single value between 0 and 255 of which the average is taken.

Then that result is checked against 128. If it's lower, pixels[i] i set to 0xff000000, otherwise it's set to 0xffffffff.

This is typical bit twiddling you'd encounter in operations on colors coded as ints. This is probably the argb scheme, where the first 8 bits of an int are the alpha (transparency), the next 8 bits are red, the next 8 are green and the last 8 bits are blue. Or a variant thereof. 0xff000000 would be completely opaque black, while 0xffffffff is completely opaque white.

Comment: +1, excellent answer! for someone who does not know that much about bitwise operations! :-)

Answer (score 5):

What it does depends on the color model and how the colors are represented in memory.

My guess is that it turns an ordinary ARGB image into a black / white image based on a 50% threshold. (Makes all pixels of less than 50% "brightness" go completely black, and all others go completely white.)

> ***What does `(pixels[i] & 0xff00 >> 8)` do?***

- `pixel[i]` you already know :-)
- `& ff00` masks out the bits in the second byte
- `>> 8` *shifts* the bits to the right, eight positions (i.e. making the right most byte fall of the edge)

> ***What is `0xff00`?***

0xff00 is hexadecimal literal for the value 65280 (or 1111111100000000 in binary)

> ***And why if grey < 128 the pixel becomes 0xff000000 or else 0xffffffff?***

This line:

```
int gray = ((pixels[i] & 0xff) +
            ((pixels[i] & 0xff00) >> 8) +
            ((pixels[i] & 0xff0000) >> 16)) / 3;
```

adds upp the red, green and blue components and divides it by three (finds out the average).

This line

```
pixels[i] = gray < 128 ? 0xff000000 : 0xffffffff;
```

presumably says that if the grayness is less than half, the pixel should be completely black, otherwise it should be completely white.

Comment: +1: 0xff000000 means its black and not transparent assuming its ARGB instead of RGB format.

Answer (score 2):

(pixels[i] & 0xff) = Blue value in 0 to 255

(pixels[i] & 0xff00) >> 8 = Green value in 0 to 255

(pixels[i] & 0xff0000) >> 16) = Red value in 0 to 255

Then you take the average of the 3 values found above.

After that depending upon the grayness, make it white or black, i.e. less than 50% gray is black else white.

Answer (score 1):

`(pixels[i] & 0xff00) >> 8` takes the second byte from the int, which represents the green color - the `&` make all bits except of the 8-15 zero and `>>` shifts them 8 bits to the right, so if the number is (in bits) 0101000100001100:

```
0101000100001100 & 0xff = 0101000100001100 & 1111111100000000 = 0101000100000000.
0101000100000000 >> 8 = 01010001
```

The same for `((pixels[i] & 0xff0000) >> 16)`.

No you take the average value of them (`/3`) and gets whether the color is closer to white or to black ( `gray < 128` ). According to this you either make the pixel black or white.

Answer (score 1):

0xFF00 it's a bitmask means 1111111100000000 in binary representation.

So when you apply this mask to number, you left higher 8 bits.

Operator >> means shift to right. For example 11110000 >> 2 = 00111100